# Laravel Eloquent : How to count member of this condition?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have 2 tables, clients and transactions

[clients and transactions tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvzgb.png)

I have to join 2 tables and count how many clients who created transaction separate by gender by card type per date.

The result should be like this.

[I need this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Az61.png)

I can join 2 tables with

```
App\Clients::join('transactions', 'clients.id', '=', 'transactions.client_id')
```

but I have no idea to seperate and count by date. Can anyone suggest please ?